# Zip files in Azure Storage into a ZipArchive object

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, zip

Here is my method I am building to add files in Azure Blob Storage to a zip archive.
I am not sure how to get the blob files to the archive.

```
    public async Task<System.IO.File> CreateLoanFilesZip(string loanFileId)
    {
        var appList = _unitOfWork.Applications.GetByLoanFile(loanFileId);
        if (appList == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        string connection = _appConfig.AzureStorageConnection;
        string containerName = _appConfig.AzureStorageContainer;
        
        //create azure service/container client
        var serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connection);
        var container = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        BlobClient blob;

        //loop each row in list of loan file applications
        foreach (var app in appList)
        {
            //get list of files from documents repo by application
            var fileList = _unitOfWork.Documents.GetListByApplication(app.ApplicationId);
            if (fileList != null)
            {
                //create a zip file with loan number and application id?
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                    {
                        foreach(var file in fileList)
                        {
                            blob = container.GetBlobClient(file.UniqueDocumentName);
                            ??--> do I need to stream the blob into the zip??
                            zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file.UniqueDocumentName, blob);
                        }
                    }

                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    return File(memoryStream, "application/zip", "application-file-download.zip");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I am not sure how to take the blob object and get it into the CreateEntryFromFile method. Do I need to create a separate stream of byte[] content?

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

This error occurs because the memory stream used in the code is released after executing the return statement. The File method creates a FileStreamResult wrapping the memory stream and returns it, but since the memory stream has been deallocated, the FileStreamResult cannot access it.

You can use `FileStreamResult` to fix it, not `System.IO.File`.

```
public async Task<FileStreamResult> CreateLoanFilesZip(string loanFileId)
{
    var appList = _unitOfWork.Applications.GetByLoanFile(loanFileId);
    if (appList == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    string connection = _appConfig.AzureStorageConnection;
    string containerName = _appConfig.AzureStorageContainer;
    
    //create azure service/container client
    var serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connection);
    var container = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    BlobClient blob;

    //loop each row in list of loan file applications
    foreach (var app in appList)
    {
        //get list of files from documents repo by application
        var fileList = _unitOfWork.Documents.GetListByApplication(app.ApplicationId);
        if (fileList != null)
        {
            //create a zip file with loan number and application id?
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/zip")
            {
                FileDownloadName = "application-file-download.zip"
            };

            using (var zip = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                foreach(var file in fileList)
                {
                    blob = container.GetBlobClient(file.UniqueDocumentName);
                    var blobResponse = await blob.DownloadAsync();
                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(blobResponse.Value.Content))
                    {
                        var entry = zip.CreateEntry(file.UniqueDocumentName);
                        using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                        {
                            await streamReader.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            memoryStream.Position = 0;
            return fileStreamResult;
        }

    }
}
```

---

You need to download the contents of the blob as a stream of bytes and then add those bytes to the archive. Here is the sample.

```
public async Task<System.IO.File> CreateLoanFilesZip(string loanFileId)
{
    var appList = _unitOfWork.Applications.GetByLoanFile(loanFileId);
    if (appList == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    string connection = _appConfig.AzureStorageConnection;
    string containerName = _appConfig.AzureStorageContainer;
    
    //create azure service/container client
    var serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connection);
    var container = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    BlobClient blob;

    //loop each row in list of loan file applications
    foreach (var app in appList)
    {
        //get list of files from documents repo by application
        var fileList = _unitOfWork.Documents.GetListByApplication(app.ApplicationId);
        if (fileList != null)
        {
            //create a zip file with loan number and application id?
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var zip = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    foreach(var file in fileList)
                    {
                        blob = container.GetBlobClient(file.UniqueDocumentName);
                        var blobResponse = await blob.DownloadAsync();
                        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(blobResponse.Value.Content))
                        {
                            var entry = zip.CreateEntry(file.UniqueDocumentName);
                            using (var entryStream = entry.Open())
                            {
                                await streamReader.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(entryStream);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                return File(memoryStream, "application/zip", "application-file-download.zip");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jason. The code looks great but I am get an error when I try to return File that "ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream."
I am wondering if memoryStream is closing, and should I use less "using" to keep the streams open?

Comment: @Ryan Sorry, I didn't notice the returned type at first, the new code snippet was updated. Hope it can help you.